# Akka Source not streaming data?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

```
val pageDataFutures : Seq[Future[PageData]]= ??? //4 api calls each resulting in a future of PageData

  def source : Source[PageData, NotUsed] = Source(
    pageDataFutures.flatMap(future => Await.result(future,atMost)).toList
  )

  source.runForeach(println)
```

I expected the source to run `'runForEach'` as and when each future is completed. But instead all the 4 api calls are made and then data in the source is all printed at once. Shouldn't it be printing the data as and available? I am using `Await` for each future. So it is guaranteed that before the next future is `Awaited` upon, the result of the previous future is available and can be used by println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html#mapasync):

> Pass incoming elements to a function that return a `Future` result. When the `Future` arrives the result is passed downstream. Up to `n` elements can be processed concurrently, but regardless of their completion time the incoming order will be kept when results complete.

```
val pageDataFutures: Seq[Future[PageData]] = ???

Source(pageDataFutures)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(x => x) // or: mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(identity)
  .runForeach(println)
```